# How to add dynamic multi-select list drop-down in admin edit.php file

Tags: magento2, array

I have create Model/Source

But I want to add this in admin multiselect dropdown list

Like: [image]

```
$fieldset->addField(
        'special', 
        'multiselect',
        [
            'label' => __('Special'),
            'title' => __('Special'),
            'name' => 'special[]',
            'values' => // How to call here ?
```

That is my option value coming like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [label] => 
            [value] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [label] => A
            [value] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [label] => B
            [value] => 2
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [label] => C
            [value] => 3
        )

        )
```

Comment: check my answer and add below code

Answer (score 1):

You can try this way..

```
$fieldset->addField(
            'special', 
            'multiselect',
            [
                'label' => __('Special'),
                'title' => __('Special'),
                'name' => 'special[]',
                'values' => [
                ["value" => 1,"label" => __("A")],
                ["value" => 2,"label" => __("B")],
                ["value" => 3,"label" => __("c")],
            ]
          ]
       );
```

Comment: That is Static values. my values coming from a table. with a select query. I want dynamic. when I will add some new value in the table then it will come in drop down.

Comment: you have custom model source filed created? then your code update in question